# Can I set appearance for GNOME Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, theme, appearance

Is there any tool to set appearance for GNOME Debian 7.2.0? I feel title bar is too thick and font is too big. I'm just leaving Ubuntu for Debian, so I'm not so familiar with it.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly would you like to customize about appearance? Which version of Debian are you using (try `cat /etc/debian_version`)? Does this relate to GNOME or GNOME 3 (two very different beasts)?

Comment: @JosephR. Could you please see my edit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several things you can do to improve the title bars in GNOME 3.

#### 1. padding

The setting for the padding is controlled in this metacity XML file, `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml`.

- Open a terminal window

  ```
  $ sudo sed -i "/title_vertical_pad/s/value=\"[0-9]\{1,2\}\"/value=\"0\"/g" \
      /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml
  ```
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- type `restart`
- hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Example

*before*

[image: before]

*after*

[image: after]

#### 2. gnome-tweak-tool

This tool allows you to customize the font that should be used for the title bar.

```
$ gnome-tweak-tool
```

*screenshot*

[image: tweak tool]

[image: ss]

#### 3. dconf-editor

You  can also change it using `dconf-editor`.

```
$ dconf-editor
```

Then navigate the hierarchy like so:

> org > gnome > desktop > wm > preferences :: titlebar-font

*screenshot*

[image: ss]

#### 4. gsettings

You can use the `get` and `set` commands to `gsettings` to find out what title bar info is being used.

*get setings*

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font
'Cantarell Bold 8'
```

*set settings*

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Cantarell Bold 10
$
```

#### References

- [Gnome 3 Massive Title Bar](http://mikeyshelpdesk.blogspot.com/2011/04/gnome-3-massive-title-bar.html)
- [How to resize font size on window title bar on gnome?](https://superuser.com/questions/502333/how-to-resize-font-size-on-window-title-bar-on-gnome)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gnome3 (and the Gnome shell), you might like some the [shell extensions available from the gnome project](https://extensions.gnome.org/) that are available to alter its default behavior and feel.

I realize this response doesn't tackle your question directly, but I found several useful extensions that removed various annoyances with the default behavior of Gnome3.